# Errors when connecting sequoiadb（error: -15）

Tags: database, sequoiadb

I have already configured system name and firewall, and "ping" command was successful, but the error occured as follows:

```
db = new Sdb();
(nofile):0 uncaught exception: -15
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The port number may be incorrectly filled. You can execute `bin/sdblist -l` in the sequoiadb installation directory to determine whether the port number is correct.

`db = new Sdb()`

The 11810 port number is used by default. If you use another port number during installation, you can specify it as follows:

`db = new Sdb("hostname:port");`